# Windows authentication for ASP.NET Webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to use Window authentication to my ASP.NET Webform pages to check user's Windows login name. I have added the Windows authentication tag with `mode="windows"`, and I have enabled Windows authentication in IIS (disabled others) for my web app.

However, it still doesn't work and the `httpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is still empty.

Is there anything I missed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This only ever (sort of) worked for users running Internet Explorer. Firefox may have also emulated this for a while, but with IE officially dead, you should look for something like SAML or OAuth instead. You might find something that will _seem_ to work, and show you the username for the currently logged in Windows user, but anything still out there is just HTTP headers -- there's nothing left that will actually validate the authentication token and you can fake it just by crafting the HTTP request to include the name in the right place.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Chromium (+Chrome, +Edge, +Brave, etc) actively supports Windows/Integrated/Kerberos/NTLM-in-HTTP just fine: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication/ - Kerberos works fine in LAN situations, but Kerberos [doesn't work over the public Internet almost by-design](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/41803/69237).

Comment: In WebForms, you should use `Page.User` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.user?view=netframework-4.8 to access the login users. Don't use `HttpContext.Current` unless you are truly aware of its usage (mostly inside HTTP modules/handlers).